# Why did I fail this low quality post review audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

Consider this review audit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/26074957

The answer is not very good, but it's an answer. Yes, it's similar to other answers, but there are multiple answers that are similar, so why pick on this one? Not to mention, the audit doesn't show you the other answers, and you'd have to manually click through to see them.

Yes, there's a link, but as far as I can tell it's not spam; it just goes to a generic PHP tutorial site. If the user is affiliated with the site, it's not at all obvious. And it's not a link-only answer. Yet it was marked as spam or offensive content. Maybe there's some other context I can't see.

So I don't really get it. And now I'm banned from all review queues. I'm not sure if there's a way to see your past audits, but I don't feel like I've done particularly badly with audits over the last few days.

Comment: The answer is not the worst but it's also not very good, either. It actually has 4 upvotes which is maybe slightly generous but it's still an answer. I agree with your choice of "Looks OK". However, the answer was flagged and deleted as spam. I suspect this is information you couldn't really see - I suspect the whole user was deleted as a spammer due to wider pattern of posts. Something you cannot judge in a review.

Comment: Yep, VLAZ is correct - that user was deleted as part of something spamming that site... however, you aren't to know that and indeed it looks fine on face value, so not a great audit. I've removed your review suspension.

Comment: FWIW, spam can be _extremely_ tricky as an audit. I thought red-flagged posts had been removed from the audit system, but I guess not. You can always use Samuel Liew's userscript (https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReviewQueueHelper.user.js) to help with this. Specifically, it skips audits, which avoids garbage audits like this one. The one link there, presumably along with additional context that you  most likely weren't involved in to see, made the answer go from a decent answer to spam. And yeah, some spam audits are extra annoying because of details like that.

Comment: @Zoe No, R/A specifically isn't meant to appear as audits IIRC, not all red flags

Comment: @Nick is correct. Answers nuked as "rude or abusive" are not candidates for audits. However, answers nuked as "spam" *are* candidates for audits. This is generally fine, as it is usually quite obvious that something is spam. In this case, it was a bit tricker to make the judgment without access to mod-only information. However, the review system should have warned you to consider that the answer was spam. When you see that warning, you can open the answer in a new tab (click "link") to view it in its original context. If it was already nuked as spam, you'll see that and easily pass the audit.