# Why did I fail this "offensive" review audit?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

**Audit:**

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/26091831

> **Message:**
>
> This post has severe quality issues. It is abusive nonsense, noise,
>   spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable – readers will
>   find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful.

I couldn't sense anything abusive in that post. Moreover, it was in good shape and I had also checked the link. It may have technical issues (I don't know PHP), but it was under "very low quality". So I checked if the word "mailgun" was the problem, but it's an API.

May I know the reason behind this audit failure?

Comment: There seem to have been some deleted posts in there if you review the timeline/revision history.

Comment: Meh. Deleted user. External link. Probably deleted as spam. It's a problem with spam posts being auto-selected as review-audits.

Comment: Just to note - the post you mention was cleared up as part of the same thing mentioned [in this Q](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397310/why-did-i-fail-this-low-quality-post-review-audit) - I've gone ahead and disputed the spam flag, and the re-deleted the post, that should keep these ones from getting used for audits again.

Comment: @JonClements I see. You are a moderator, do you know if this counts to how many more review audits I should fail to get a ban?

Comment: @ArdentCoder the exact details aren't disclosed (and there's no easy way to determine it anyway) but apart from this one (which isn't really a fair audit - as per my comment on the post I linked to) you haven't failed an audit that lead to a review suspension in over 30 days, so no doubt, if you do your best and don't fall afoul of any more unfair audits then it's not something you should have to worry about.

Comment: It's not offensive. It's spam. There are multiple options in that list. The post could meet *any or all* of them.

Comment: @CodyGray I took it from their conclusion: "readers will find it offensive or repulsive" where most of the previous adjectives matched "offensive". It really felt like they mean it to be offensive, nevertheless interpretation is subjective.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, looks like we need to rephrase that message. It is confusing and leading users to the wrong impression. Especially since we don't actually use offensive/repulsive/abusive posts as audits. You're far more likely to get spam (or just garbage). Perhaps post a separate feature request for revising the message?

Comment: Thanks, I'll post one now after I check for any possible duplicates.

Comment: @JonClements Here's another one: "https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/26103953"... *"if you do your best and don't fall afoul of **any more unfair audits**"*?!

Comment: @CodyGray Now that it's becoming more frequent, perhaps post a separate feature request for revising the selection of review audits?

Comment: @ArdentCoder okay... that's a little weird... will have to look more into that later but for now you're good again...

Comment: @JonClements My prediction was true, fourth day: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/26118763. You very well know the reason why I came back to these comments instead of making a post.