# Revise "This post has severe quality issues" message?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, review-audits

> **Message:**
>
> This post has severe quality issues. It is abusive nonsense, noise,
>   spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable – readers will
>   find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful.

This message *generally* serves for a "low quality post". But see the conclusion of the message:

> readers will find it offensive or repulsive

It really feels like they mean it to be offensive because most of those words collectively match "offensive".

What if someone receives that message for spam? It might leave a reviewer confused like it happened in [my case.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397348/why-did-i-fail-this-offensive-review-audit)

Won't it be better to rephrase that message? Then there's the word "or" in the conclusion, so what about a separate message for spam?

Answer (score 1):

I do see where you are coming from, how about these change I've made,

> This post has *several* <strike>severe</strike> quality issues. It *can be considered or mistaken* <strike>is</strike> as abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic, or otherwise irredeemable – readers *might find* <strike>will</strike> it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful.

This still gives out a rather calm statement **yet** sends the message across which is ultimately what the site wants.

Comment: Why would it have **several** issues? The issue might be a single one.